# why thread function's param is a ref, the complier failed?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, reference

i feel confused about the ref as parameters when using thread library, below is the code:

```
#include "../include.h"  // include some header file
class A { 
 public:
  A(unordered_map<int, int>& m) : m(m) {  
  }
  void Start() {
    std::thread(test1, m); 
  }
 private:
  static void test1(unordered_map<int, int>&  m) {  // complie failed, if the ref change to value(remove &), it's ok, thats confused me
    for (auto i : m) {
      cout << i.first << i.second << endl;
    }   
  }
  unordered_map<int, int> & m;
};

int main() {
  unordered_map<int, int> m = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
  A a(m);
  a.Start();
}
```

when i let test1's params be ref, it failed, and come out a lot of msg:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/thread:39:0,
                 from ./../include.h:6,
                 from ./test@classref.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(std::unordered_map<int, int>))(std::unordered_map<int, int>&)>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/thread:137:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(std::unordered_map<int, int>&); _Args = {std::unordered_map<int, int, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > >&}]’
./test@classref.cpp:10:25:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1697:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(std::unordered_map<int, int>))(std::unordered_map<int, int>&)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1727:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(std::unordered_map<int, int>))(std::unordered_map<int, int>&)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^
```

but good if the params be value, i dont know the difference, can anyone help on this?

Is there any special things i dont know about the thread function parameters?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread#Notes),

> The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value. If
>   a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has
>   to be wrapped (e.g. with std::ref or std::cref).

So,

```
  void Start() {
    auto t = std::thread(test1, std::ref(m)); 
    t.join(); // so it waits for the thread to finish printing for your example.
  }
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/05hmoR)

Comment: Thanks a lot @rmawatson  it works! but i still a little confused. the parameters i passed is already a refence(the member variable m is a ref, not a value), why should i wrap it as ref again?

Comment: As the arguments are by default moved or copied, requiring std::ref is to make you be explicit about wanting to use a reference in the thread function.  Think about what could happen if your class instance went out of scope (along with its member variable) before the thread had finished printing - it will crash. using std::ref to pass the variable is just to make you be verbose about what you're doing.